# How to enable Subdag in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

In Airflow document, it is mentioned as below

"Subdags must have a schedule and be enabled

Even though subdags are triggered as part of a larger dag, if their schedule is set to None or ‘@once’, the subdag operator will succeed without doing anything".

But not clear, how we can enable the Subdags. Is there any way to enable the Subdag?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SubDAG like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

default_args = {
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 12, 16),
}

schedule_interval = "@daily"

def create_subdag(main_dag, subdag_id):
    subdag = DAG('{0}.{1}'.format(main_dag.dag_id, subdag_id),
                default_args=default_args)
    DummyOperator(
        task_id='foo',
        dag=subdag)
    return subdag

main_dag = DAG(
    dag_id='main_dag',
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1
)

my_subdag = SubDagOperator(
    task_id='subdag',
    dag=main_dag,
    retries=3,
    subdag=create_subdag(main_dag, 'subdag')
)
```